# How can I get Electrum running under Debian with a restrictive firewall?

Tags: electrum, linux, port, firewall

So I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and am using iptables to disallow all outgoing and incoming traffic by default except that which I explicitly permit.

I keep on being disconnected with a red dot in the bottom right. I already tried selecting servers manually and opening port 5002. When running `netstat -pln` other strange ports show up. If possible I'd like to only use port 80 and 443. Which ports do I need to open in which way to get it working? Or is there anything else I need to configure to get it working?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's a general system administration question, not specific to Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Tor: under network options set the proxy to `SOCKS5 localhost 9050`.